# DocumentDB order by results

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

in DocumentDB I've some documents like this

```
{
  "Code": "123456",
  "ScanLog": [
    {
      "TimeStamp": 20160224115507
    },
    {
      "TimeStamp": 20160224115641
    }
  ]
  "LastScanTimeStamp": 20160224115641
}
```

I've made this LINQ query in C#:

```
   var Query = client.CreateDocumentQuery().OrderByDescending(c => c.LastScanTimeStamp).SelectMany(a => a.ScanLog.Select(b => new { Code = a.Code, TimeStamp = b.TimeStamp })).AsDocumentQuery();
   var feedResp = await Query.ExecuteNextAsync();
```

and this is the result:

```
[
  {
    "Code": "123456",
    "TimeStamp": 20160224115507
  },
  {
    "Code": "123456",
    "TimeStamp": 20160224115641
  },
  {
    "Code": "abcdef",
    "TimeStamp": 20160224101641
  },
  {
    "Code": "abcdef",
    "TimeStamp": 20160224105641
  }
]
```

To this result I apply another order in this way:

```
feedResp.OrderByDescending(a => a.TimeStamp).AsEnumerable();
```

The response is:

```
[
  {
    "Code": "123456",
    "TimeStamp": 20160224115641
  },
  {
    "Code": "123456",
    "TimeStamp": 20160224115507
  },
  {
    "Code": "abcdef",
    "TimeStamp": 20160224105641
  },
  {
    "Code": "abcdef",
    "TimeStamp": 20160224101641
  }
]
```

Now if I make the initial query with LINQ operator Take() specifying a limit for the retrieved items, I lost some elements in the result.
Why??

Comment: Your original response had 4 results. What value did you specify for Take? If it was less than 4 you will obviously get fewer results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this query, you achieve a JOIN withing the same documents, meaning that if you have 4 documents, each with 4 logs, you have 16 documents.

Linq creates the query dynamically, maybe what is happening is that the Take is acting over the documents and not the result of the query.

What I'd try is to use the [FeedOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/microsoft.azure.documents.linq.documentqueryable.createdocumentquery.aspx) on the Document query and specify the number of max results I want to obtain there.

```
var Query = client.CreateDocumentQuery("my_collection_uri",new FeedOptions(){MaxItemCount=4}).OrderByDescending(c => c.LastScanTimeStamp).SelectMany(a => a.ScanLog.Select(b => new { Code = a.Code, TimeStamp = b.TimeStamp })).AsDocumentQuery();
var feedResp = await Query.ExecuteNextAsync();
```

Comment: I've already tried with the FeedOptions parameter but the result is the same. If I've a join result of 16 documents, as you said, applying the Take operator or FeedOptions parameter, for taking max 10 results, and the order by, I take the first and second documents then it skips some next documents then retrieve the other next documents.

Comment: I thought that that's what you wanted to achieve. I understand now that what you want is to apply the Take on the Documents **before** the join occurs, so a Take of 10 could yielf 40 results (if each document had 4 logs), is that correct?

Comment: I've solved the problem. Really it is not a real problem because the results set from DocumentDB is correct according to the structure of the documents. I've spent much time analizing the results then I saw it's a correct result.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably put the take before your order. In that case the take takes some elements from the unordered result and than the ordering takes place. If you do the take after the order, you will get the set from the ordered elements. Which is probably what you expected as result.

Comment: I've put the Take immediately before the .AsDocumentQuery call on the first query.